# How to get File.OpenText to return non-nullable StreamReader

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

Consider the following:

```
var lines = new List<string>();
string path = "FileName.txt";
var reader = File.OpenText(path);
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
}
```

When setting the `Nullable` flag to `enable`, in csproj, `reader` is a `StreamReader?` which gives a `Possible null reference argument for parameter 'item'` compiler warning. Even if I explicitly set `reader` to `StreamReader`, the issue persists.

Is there a way around this warning without turning off `Nullable`?

Comment: `File.OpenText()` will always return an instance of `StreamReader` or throws, it will never return `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce all that code down to just two Nullable-friendly lines:

```
string path = "FileName.txt";
var lines = File.ReadLines(path).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe, that the warning included in the description of the problem is not full. I reproduced the problem and got the next compiler warning: `CS8604 Possible null reference argument for parameter 'item' in 'void List<string>.Add(string item)`. The warning occurs in the next line

```
lines.Add(reader.ReadLine());
```

because `List<string> lines` is a list of non-nullable `string` values, and the method `StreamReader.ReadLine()` can return nullable `string?` (see [reference source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/StreamReader.cs,763)). So that in the above line of code these is an attempt to add `null` string value into the list of non-nullable strings.

To fix the problem you can use either of the next approaches:

- ***[Use null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).*** You know for sure that the result of the expression `reader.ReadLine()` cannot be `null` because it is executed when the end of the stream is not reached. Therefore you can use null-forgiving operator to suppress the warning:

  ```
  lines.Add(reader.ReadLine()!);
  ```
- ***Check if the result of the expression `reader.ReadLine()` is null.*** If you use the next code the warning will disappear:

  ```
  string? line = reader.ReadLine();
  if (line != null)
      lines.Add(line);
  ```

---

**UPDATE**

As @IanRingrose pointed out in the comment a condition `line != null` could be used in the loop instead of the condition `!reader.EndOfStream()`. Using such condition solution can be made more clear:

```
string? line;

while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lines.Add(line);
}
```

Now we don't need to use null-forgiving operator or additional condition in the loop body.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question about the nullability of the reader itself: `reader` is a `StreamReader?` due to a decision with NRT that use of `var` will deduce the type of the variable as *nullable*.

See this [section of the spec:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/nullable-reference-types-specification#nullable-implicitly-typed-local-variables)

> **nullable implicitly typed local variables**
>
> `var` infers an annotated type for reference types. For instance, in `var s = "";` the `var` is inferred as `string?`.

The [language design notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-12-18.md#var) explain this decision. Ultimately they conclude:

> Make `var` have a nullable annotated type and infer the flow type as normal.

The idea being that since there is not a syntax for `var?`, the type is deduced as the least strict (ie, allow `null` assignment to the variable later). Ultimately the nullability *should* be tracked via flow analysis.

That said, using `OpenText` is known to always return a non-`null` object (otherwise it throws) and has a [non-nullable return type](https://source.dot.net/System.IO.FileSystem/a.html#019a819484daf2d2). To remove your issue, simply declare your variable directly as `StreamReader`:

```
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(path);
```

As the other answers point out, I think you are confused about the actual error and where it is occurring. The only place "item" would occur is when calling `List<>.Add`. Of course, this is because `StreamReader.ReadLine` can return `null` and your list is declared as `List<string>` and not `List<string?>`

Your choices are to:

- change the type of the list (probably not)
- use null-forgiving operator `reader.ReadLine()!` (maybe, but only if guaranteed)
- use a local variable and add a check for `null` before adding to the list (either directly or by modifying your loop condition to peform both an assignment and a null check)